# POST convert to GET when I want to fetch formData?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I want to send an image to server

my code works perfect in Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90

**BUT**

in Mozilla Firefox (version 69.0.1) POST method changes to GET with this error

**Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent.**

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/...

Request method: GET

Status code: 200

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" >

<div class="col">
 <label for="images" class="control-label">image</label>
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images" id="images" >
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>
   </div>
</div>

</form>
```

```
<script>
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit' , async function(event) {

let images = document.querySelector('input[name="images"]');

let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('images' , images.files[0] );

try {
         const response = await fetch('http://exampleurl.com/profile', {

             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
               'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
               'X-CSRF-Token': "<%= req.csrfToken() %>",
             },
             body: formData,
             credentials: 'same-origin'
             });
             } catch (error) {
               console.error(error);
    }
    })

</script>
```

*I can't use method ="POST" and enctype= "multipart/form-data" in the form because **csrf tokens** can't implement in forms with multipart/form-data enctype*

Comment: change this `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">` with this '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">' first and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your form might be submitting twice.

1) AJAX event handler
2) The submit button in the form actually posting the form through html

Try adding the event handler to the form itself, rather than the submit button. 
There you can prevent the form from doing what it wants to do so only your AJAX request will go through. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event